# Conditional SELECT based COUNT

Tags: mysql, sql, select, count

I have a table with two variables that occur multiple times, each, for the occurrence of each:

i.e.

```
Customer        City
Bob             New York
Bob             Denver
Bob             Denver
Greg            Denver
Greg            Denver
Greg            New York
```

Example:

```
SELECT Customer FROM tableName WHERE COUNT( SELECT Customer,City FROM tableName)=1;
```

I want to get unique cities for each unique customer name and count how many cities that customer has. How do you do this in mysql?

Comment: use `group by` and count.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if you want to get the repetitions of a city for each customer or the total number of different cities so I'm going to put both values:

```
select Customer, City, count(City) as CityCount, TotalDistinctCities
from CustomerCities
join (select Customer as cust, count(distinct City) as TotalDistinctCities
  from CustomerCities
  group by Customer)
as CityCount on cust=Customer   
group by Customer, City, TotalDistinctCities
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `distinct` modified in your `count` call:

```
SELECT   customer, COUNT(DISTINCT city)
FROM     tablename
GROUP BY customer
```